# Cannot pass column names to function in r

Tags: r

I try to create a function to generate dummy variables, but I find the column name cannot be recognized when I create a trail function.

here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(gridExtra)

## set the file path
file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Carloszone/Kaggle-Cases/main/01-Titanic/train.csv"


## load data and name it "dat_train"
dat_train = read.csv(file)

## transform columns' data types
dat_train <- dat_train %>% transform(PassengerId = as.character(PassengerId),
                                     Survived = as.factor(Survived),
                                     Pclass = as.factor(Pclass),
                                     Sex = as.factor(Sex),
                                     SibSp = as.factor(SibSp),
                                     Parch = as.factor(Parch),
                                     Ticket = as.character(Ticket),
                                     Cabin = as.character(Cabin),
                                     Embarked = as.factor(Embarked)
)

## create functions
x <- function(data, name){
  dummy <- model.matrix(~name, data)[,-1] %>% head()
  return(dummy)
}

y <- function(data){
  dummy <- model.matrix(~Pclass, data)[,-1] %>% head()
  return(dummy)
}

## test functions
x(dat_train, "Pclass")

y(dat_train)
```

At first, I create the function "x", but I find it doesn't work:

```
 Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Therefore, I create the function "y", and it runs well.

```
  Pclass2 Pclass3
1       0       1
2       0       0
3       0       1
4       0       0
5       0       1
6       0       1
```

So, I think the question is the column name fail to pass to the function.
But I don't know how to deal with the problem.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function. Just add `model.matrix(~data[,name], data)`

Comment: Take a look at nonstandard evaluation with base R (`substitute()`) or tidy eval (`enquo()`) for passing column names.

Comment: Hi, George, thank you for your help. now my code works!

Comment: Hi, jwarz. thank you for your information. it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function work by using e.g. `as.formula`:

```r
## create functions
x <- function(data, name){
  fmla <- as.formula(paste("~", name))
  dummy <- model.matrix(fmla, data)[,-1] %>% head()
  return(dummy)
}

## test functions
x(dat_train, "Pclass")
#>   Pclass2 Pclass3
#> 1       0       1
#> 2       0       0
#> 3       0       1
#> 4       0       0
#> 5       0       1
#> 6       0       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Further information can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50054285/9978136) comment.